# Проверка на существование всех переменных в GET запросе

Tags: php

Скажем есть такая ссылка

> site.ru/page?url=1&obj=2&hr=3&blablabla=4

И есть массив такого рода:

```
$arr = array('url', 'obj');
```

Как проверить все переменные из GET запроса на существование? и если переменной в массиве нету, выдать 404.

В данном примере должно выдать 404-ю т.к. переменных `hr` и `blablabla` не существует.

Comment: 1 класс `if(!isset($_GET['url'])) redirect 404`

Comment: Это вы проверили на существование переменной 'url' а не на существование сторонних переменных во всем GET запросе.

Comment: А я бы даже усложнил задачу, чтобы, например, 'url' не могло идти после 'obj' или повторяться. Хорошо, когда между исходными и сериализованными данными взаимно-однозначное соответствие.

Comment: да конечно хорошо бы)) Но пока я даже не получается решить задачу с основной проблемой, а именно наличием ненужны переменных в GET запросе.

Comment: Как еще можно улучшить постановку задачи: `$arr = array('url' => 'url', 'obj' => 'index')`. Дальше вы можете использовать фильтры, чтобы проверить, адекватные ли значения у `url` и `obj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как то так видимо?

```
$allow = ['url', 'obj'];
foreach($_GET as $param => $value){
    if(!in_array($param, $allow)){
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Еще вариант вычислить расхождение массивов:

```
if(count(array_diff_key($_GET, $allow))){
    .... // 404
}
```

Comment: ваш код выведет 404 даже если `url` и `obj` существуют. так как производится проверка на существования того, чего не может быть в `$allow`

Comment: так вроде и написано? _"и если переменной в массиве нету, выдать 404"._

Comment: почему то вылезает ошибка с жалобой на эту строку $allow = ['foto', 'obj'];

Comment: @vasa666 пхп наверное старый, `$allow = array('url', 'obj');`

Comment: Первый вариант заработал!))) а вот этот if(count(array_diff_key($_GET, $allow))){
    .... // 404
} почему то отсекает даже с переменными в массиве

Comment: да, я почему то подумал что вопрос в другом